# Clone Unity Dock for All Users?

Tags: unity, launcher, icons, clone, user-profile

I've spent 3 days trying to figure out how to clone the Unity dock from my firstuser profile in Ubuntu 12.04 to all of the other profiles I'm hoping to create.

I've read where the /etc/skel folder contents get populated to all new profiles but this doesn't seem to include the dock or the desktop folders and icons.

I've also copied the entire contents of my /home/firstuser folder to my /home/seconduser folder (including .* files) but the dock is still showing the stock icons and not the icons I've designated in my firstuser profile dock.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the user permissions over the files when doing this:

```
cp /home/firstuser/.* /home/seconduser/
sudo chown -R seconduser:seconduser /home/seconduser/
```

otherwise, they will not be read and you will stay with stocks.

Comment: Many thanks!  I'm still wrapping my head around some of the basics for Linux.  Permissions is obviously one of them.